# Using JPA repository access in constructor of Service class

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have spring boot app with a service (annotated `@Service`) and having several JPA repository interfaces.

Now I want to read entries form a database during the start of the service cause the JPA repository and the database connection is done before anything else.

So I have decided to put that code into the constructor of the service.

The question is:

- Is this a correct way to initialise some attributes of a service only once at the start of  the application (configuration which is stored in database)?
- I have taken a look at `@PostConstruct` and InitializingBean interface (but they make it hard to write a test for them ? (Maybe I overlooked something here?) is this a better way?

**Update I**
The service for configuration only contains an injection (via constructor) of a single JPA repository (table which contains the configuration parts).
within the constructor only a few values will be read from the database (at the moment 4) and assigned to attributes of the service.
(I have simplified that a little bit and drilled it down to the most important parts here):

```
@Service
public class ConfigService {
  private final ConfigRepository configRepository;

  private final Duration configValueOne;

  public ConfigService(ConfigRepository configRepository) {
    this.configValueOne=convertFromRepoToDuration("ATTRIBUTE");
  }

  public Duration configValueOne() {
    return configValueOne;        
  }
```

}

**Update II:**

- The configuration will be used in several areas of the application that's the reason I have implemented that as a service.
- A change of the values in the db will take only effect after a restart of the application which is exactly intended that way.

Comment: `@PostConstruct` seems appropriate, why is testing hard for it?

Comment: I personally wouldn't store application-specific initializations in `@Service` Classes and instead write a Configuration class for that. But - besides from my architectural personal opinion - from a technical POV the constructor is totally fine.

Comment: The constructor approach can very easily tested with mockito, but the setup `@PostConstruct` i need to call it manually which forces me to make the method at least package visible. and furthermore the `@PostConstruct` approach means I can make the attributes final in my class.

Comment: `@PostConstruct` can easily be tested, but I'd prefer the Constructor. It's the most non-Spring-compatible way and therefore recommended. Like Constructor Injection is preferred over `@Autowired`.

Comment: @Clijsters But If I correctly understood the configuration classes they are usually used to define configuration which is put into application.properties which I don't want to do..Or do I misunderstand a thing?

Comment: @Clijsters Can you give a tip/example/link how to do testing with `@PostConstruct` that in a good way?

Comment: What kind of initializing data? If it are just properties you might even be better of creating a JDBC backed `PropertySource` and use regular `@Value`. If that isn't the case you might want to consider a `FactoryBean` to create the service. If the repository isn't part of the things the service needs to operate (only to retrieve config) you might (or should?) externalize that.

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes and no. The semantics of `@Configuration` doesnt limit to properties, it can also contain several initializations, pre loading and so on. and don't confuse them with `@ConfigurationProperties`

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes I where happy to do. Maybe you give us some extra information (in an edit so we sont get too chatty) on what kind of data you mean and what meaning it has for the app and for the service.

Comment: I would be interested in opening a chat Room for that, because it looks like a common problem in daily business with many possible maybe-opinion-based solutions.
I'm also curious whether that question would better fit on SoftwareEngineeringSE.

Comment: @Clijsters The values in the are configuration values which influences some other parts of the app but should be changeable directly at runtime and should taken effect only after a restart of the application. (Updated the question; If something is missing just say so I will add updates).

Comment: @Clijsters Could you give a hint how `@PostConstruct` can easily being tested? If so I'm absolutely fine with `@PostContruct`...

Comment: @khmarbaise I would suggest a JDBC (or maybe even a JPA) based `PropertySource` instead of a service/repo combo. That way it integrates nicely with the remainder of Spring to obtain configuration values. You could even make it work with `@Refresh` (when using Spring Cloud Config) and have direct updates of the properties. Or you can use Spring Cloud Config which support JDBC out-of-the-box (although it requires a configuration server, instead of just a single application).