# Initialisation Order of Integration Tests annotated with @SpringBootTest / @Sql

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, integration-testing

We have a larger Spring boot application and a number of integration tests which are annotated by `@SpringBootTest` and having number of services.

Within the integration tests we have a number of them which are using `@Sql` to setup in memory db (as in real world) and having services which are reading values from the database base at the start time of the service.

Based on analysing/reading we have found that the order of initialisation is:

- ServletTestExecutionListener – configures Servlet API mocks for a WebApplicationContext
- DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener – handles the @DirtiesContext annotation for “before” modes
- DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener – provides dependency injection for the test instance
- DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener – handles the @DirtiesContext annotation for “after” modes
- TransactionalTestExecutionListener – provides transactional test execution with default rollback semantics
- SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener – runs SQL scripts configured using the @Sql annotation

(Hint: The above list is copied from https://www.baeldung.com/spring-testexecutionlistener).

This means in consequence that it is not possible to write an integration tests with `@SpringBootTest` in which a service will read values from a database during the initialisation. This also means it's not possible to use `@PostConstruct` as alternative.

**The question is: Is there an easy way to change that order?**

I already tried to register a different test execution listener like this:

```
@TestExecutionListeners(
    {
        SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.class,
        ServletTestExecutionListener.class,
        DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener.class,
        DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
        DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
        TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class
    }
)
```

but it does not execute my scripts first (Maybe I'm doing something wrong).

Apart from that If I start the spring boot application with a service as described (reading values from database) above it will work perfectly which puzzles me a bit. Why is there a big difference between an integration test and the real world application?

Maybe I misunderstand a thing here, but it looks like the order in spring test (@SpringBootTest) is different than in real world application?

This question is related to [Using JPA repository access in constructor of Service class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62679679/296328)

Comment: This does not answer your question but from the documentation: "you can declare the @Sql annotation on a test class or test method to configure individual SQL statements ... that should be run ... before or after an integration test method". So this is not a good fit for SQL that should run before the beans are created.

Comment: I know that I can run separated statements. But I have a number of SQL scripts which are correctly defined in the annotation `@Sql(scripts={"..."}` and that does not solve the problem cause the order is defined that SQL part is running at the last position which is the real problem.